# AspectJ: Defining pointcuts for methods referenced by name without being called

Tags: java, scala, aspectj

Say we have some code similar to this;

```
val getterFunction: () => Any = obj.getSomeValue

higherOrderFunction(getterFunction)
```

Note that we're not actually *calling* `getSomeValue`- we're simply storing a reference to the function. This means that `getterFunction` is now an anonymous function, without any knowledge of it's origin. So if we were to define a pointcut for when `getSomeValue()` gets called/executed we wouldn't get a match.

What I'm trying to do instead is to define a joinpoint that would trigger when `getSomeValue` is *referenced*, and stored in the variable `getterFunction`. Is this possible using AspectJ?

Comment: Would you mind preparing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me instead of just a snippet? I am not a Scala guy, but an AspectJ guy. I would like to look into it if I had a compileable example I could run my aspect against.